# Spring boot multi-module project and aws ECS services

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ecs

If I have a multi module project. Spring Boot, using gradle.

Because it has multi modules it has several jars when build it.

I wonder how multi module project could be mapped to the concept of ECS service & tasks?

I guess there is no magic of ECS to know that that module belongs to the app and it will be separately scaled in out? Even though there is spring @Service classes live in each module they can not be independently mapped to ECS service?

(I guess I had to research a bit more before asking, but still)

Answer (score 1):

Spring's @Service has NOTHING to do with ECS's services, other they use the same word. They are completely different things. And AWS ECS has absolutely no idea that you are even running Java, much less Spring. ECS just runs the docker containers you tell it to run.

If you want ECS to scale each module separately, you will have to deploy each module as a separate ECS service.

Comment: that what I thought. but there is also DockerImageAsset in ECS that seems has to do with mapping multi module application to ECS. whether it is spring or not.  For example "app" and "lib": `const appAsset = new DockerImageAsset(stack, 'AppAsset', {
  directory: path.join(__dirname, '../app'),
});

const libAsset = new DockerImageAsset(stack, 'LibAsset', {
  directory: path.join(__dirname, '../lib'),
});`

Comment: Is that from the AWS CDK? It's really difficult to read or understand that code in a comment. Each of your spring modules has to be a separate docker image. Each docker image will have to be deployed as a separate ECS service. It is only at the ECS service level that ECS can auto-scale, so you have to have a separate service for each module if you want to scale them separately.